# Create GFF3 feature exporter

Tags: gff3, homework

Problem Statement

> The GFF3 format is a commonly-used one in bioinformatics for
> representing sequence  annotation. You can find the specification
> here:
>
> http://www.sequenceontology.org/gff3.shtml
>
> The genome and annotation for Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288C is on the
> class server here:
>
> ```
> /home/jorvis1/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae_S288C.annotation.gff
> ```
>
> Note that this same file has both the annotation feature table and the
> FASTA sequence for the  molecules referenced. (See the '##FASTA'
> directive in the specification.) Within the feature table another
> column of note is the 9 th , where we can store any key=value  pairs
> relevant to that row's feature such as ID, Ontology_term or Note. Your
> task is to write a GFF3 feature exporter. A user should be able to run
> your script like this:
>
> ```
> $ export_gff3_feature.py --source_gff=/path/to/some.gff3 --type=gene --attribute=ID --value=YAR003W
> ```
>
> There are 4 arguments here that correspond to values in the GFF3
> columns. In this case, your  script should read the path to a GFF3
> file, find any gene (column 3) which has an ID=YAR003W (column 9).
> When it finds this, it should use the coordinates for that feature
> (columns 4, 5 and 7)  and the FASTA sequence at the end of the
> document to return its FASTA sequence. Your script should work
> regardless of the parameter values passed, warning the user if no
> features were found that matched their query. (It should also check
> and warn if more than one  feature matches the query.)
>
> The output should just be printed on STDOUT (no writing to a file is
> necessary.) It should have a header which matches their query, like
> this:
>
> > gene:ID:YAR003W .... sequence here ...
>
> As an extra challenge, you can format the sequence portion of the
> FASTA output as 60-characters per line, which follows the standard.

So far I have this below. I'm not even sure if this is correct to start with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

for line in open("Saccharomyces_cerevisiae_S288C.annotation.gff"):
   line1 = line.rstrip()
   if line.startswith("#"):
       continue
   column = line1.split("\t")
   if len(column) != 9:
       continue
   id = column[8]
   type = column[2]
```

Can anyone help me with this? I'm totally lost. Thank you!

Comment: Was there any restriction about using already developed packages for this purpose? If not : https://biopython.org/wiki/GFF_Parsing , you can wrap your script around with this plus argparse to work from the console: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: @Avamys please add this as a separate answer. Comments should only be used for transient information that can help improve or supplement questions or answers. See [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer looks like a good start. You'll probably want to use sys.argv, argparse, or another argument parsing tool to read in options from the command line, then compare them to the fields (e.g. the "type" argument gets compared with the type column).

Given that attributes can be arranged in an arbitrary order, you'll probably need to read all of them from each line and store in a dict in order to determine whether the target is present. A regular expression search is another way to do that.

There are a few libraries available (e.g. from biopython) for reading and subsetting FASTA records.